# how to create index names

Tags: code-request

I have file names in the form of `"ARG_time.xls"`, `"AUS_time.xls"` and so on. I like to create `time` stamped file name as `"ARG_2012.xls"`, `"AUS_2012.xls"` and so on. I apply:

```
Table[
 {"ARG_time.xls", "AUS_time.xls", "AUT_time.xls", "BEL_time.xls", 
  "BGR_time.xls"}, {time, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015}
 ]
```

This does not work of course. Is there an easy way to create this table to have file names as

```
{"ARG_2010.xls", "AUS_2010.xls", "AUT_2010.xls", "BEL_2010.xls", "BGR_2010.xls"},
(...)
{"ARG_2015.xls", "AUS_2015.xls", "AUT_2015.xls", "BEL_2015.xls", "BGR_2015.xls"}
```

Thanks

Comment: Look up `StringTemplate`

Comment: `Table[{"ARG_" <> ToString[time] <> ".xls", 
  "AUS_" <> ToString[time] <> ".xls", 
  "AUT_" <> ToString[time] <> ".xls", 
  "BEL_" <> ToString[time] <> ".xls", 
  "BGR_" <> ToString[time] <> ".xls"}, {time, {2010, 2011, 2012, 2013,
    2014, 2015}}]`

Comment: @corey979: It works just as I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l1 = {"ARG_time.xls", "AUS_time.xls", "AUT_time.xls", "BEL_time.xls", "BGR_time.xls"};
times = {2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015};

StringReplace[l1, "time" -> #] & /@ IntegerString[times]
```

> ```
>  {{"ARG_2010.xls", "AUS_2010.xls", "AUT_2010.xls", "BEL_2010.xls", "BGR_2010.xls"}, 
>   {"ARG_2011.xls", "AUS_2011.xls", "AUT_2011.xls", "BEL_2011.xls", "BGR_2011.xls"},  
>   {"ARG_2012.xls", "AUS_2012.xls",  "AUT_2012.xls", "BEL_2012.xls", "BGR_2012.xls"}, 
>   {"ARG_2013.xls",  "AUS_2013.xls", "AUT_2013.xls", "BEL_2013.xls", "BGR_2013.xls"}, 
>   {"ARG_2014.xls", "AUS_2014.xls", "AUT_2014.xls", "BEL_2014.xls", "BGR_2014.xls"}, 
>   {"ARG_2015.xls", "AUS_2015.xls", "AUT_2015.xls", "BEL_2015.xls", "BGR_2015.xls"}}
> ```

```
Table[StringReplace["time" -> time]@l1, {time, IntegerString[times]}]
```

> same result